# Asyncio.create_task() and asyncio.gather() running in sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have an API, which takes a long time to do. So I want to split it into many smaller jobs, then run them in parallel and wait for the result before sending the response.

My snip code:

```
@app.post("/data")
async def get_tsp_events:
    query = [foo, bar, foo, bar]
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(do_work(param1, param2)) for query in queries]
    events = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return events

async def do_something(arg1, arg2):
    log("Start time")
    # This take a lot of times
    events = [event for event in range(10000000000)]
    log("End time")
    return events
```

As I see, all task is run in sequence just like normal code (without using `asyncio.create_task()` and `asyncio.gather`)
I'm new in Python and my question is:

- I'm wrong or not ? Where ?
- There are any solution can help me ?

Thank you all

Comment: Replace `pass` with something that will simulate an IO activity, e.g. `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` and you should see the result you expect. A coroutine that doesn't await anything is a coroutine in name only - it is only when a coroutine suspends that others get a chance to run.

Comment: @user4815162342. I have code in that function. Not just `pass`. I've just update it

Comment: But does the code you have in the function `await` anything? (See the second sentence of my initial coomment.) Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue, along with the example of output you expect and what you actually observe?

Comment: As I described. Assume that I have a list of events. I want to update information for all events. I can iterate over list to do in sequence. But i want to split into 2 smaller list and do it in parallel. How can i do that?

Comment: Just like a have execute my `do_something()` function 1000 times. How I can do in parallel ?

Comment: asyncio is for parallelizing IO-bound tasks, not for CPU-bound ones. Based on what you've shown so far, it's the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

1. In fact, async and await didn't introduce real parallel, they works when you do some underlying "asynchronous" operations like [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/), [aiofile](https://pypi.org/project/aiofile/). Nevertheless, they only bring concurrency for IO-bound tasks.
2. If you want real parallel for CPU-bound tasks, use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).